# Topology drawing tool

Tags: topology

I need to draw some simple network topology charts, suggestions of some good tools appreciated.

Edit: love freeware  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SmartDraw](http://www.smartdraw.com) is the best there is. It costs, but is worth the dosh.

Answer (score 6):

Try [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) - it's open source and cross platform.

Answer (score 2):

Easy to use, full of features, good looking and for free - [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is great if you want the layout to be automatic.

Answer (score 1):

Omnigraffle if you want to do it by hand and have a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

NetworkNotepad is a useful, if quirky, programme.